# Dll Debugging fails to show outputdebugstring

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, dll, 64-bit, windbg

Before creating a dll i have placed OutputDebugString throughout the code so that i can see the exact function where the dll maybe failing. Now i have created a visual studio project which loads this dll using LoadLibrary function.The loadlibrary call is successful but i cannot see any of the output debug string when i use WinDBG to debug the EXE.According to me I should see at least the output debug string which is near the code where the dll starting point is present.Can anybody tell me what maybe the problem?

Further info:-

The dll contains c++ code and is a 64 bit dll.

I am using visual studio 10 and the OS i am using is Windows 7 64 bit.

The WinDBG is also 64 bit.

Comment: First thing to check is the "Modules" view to make sure you are loading the copy of the DLL that you think you are loading.

Comment: I have re-checked it and i am sure that i am loading the correct DLL and its modules.

Comment: You can check the pdbs by entering either '!chksym mydll' or the undocumented '!itoldyouso mydll', both are synonymous, also does listing the modules display any errors such as unable to verify checksum after enter 'lm'?

Comment: When i press 'lm' i get just the deferred modules with no errors.

Comment: If you put an OutputDebugString in your program where you know it has to be run, does it output text?

Comment: @Zipper For code anywhere inside the Dll it does not but for code inside my visual studio project (where i call this DLL) it works.

Comment: You are building a debug version of the DLL right?  If so put a breakpoint in one the functions that calls OutputDebugString and step through it and make sure it is actually executing the line you think.

Comment: @DesertIce did you ever get a resolution on this?  I'm having the same problem.  (needless to say, I also can't debug-step through my loaded DLL either, I'm about ready to try manually writing to a log-file on disk)

Comment: see this possibly related MS bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775974/outputdebugstring-not-outputting-to-debug-output-window-in-64-bit-build

Comment: @ebyrob - Never got a resolution to this i am afraid.